# Writing on a separate lines in a text file

Tags: python, computer-science

```
import random

device = input("What device do you have? Phone or PC(laptop included). If other 
please specify ").upper()

make = ("")

model= ("")

verison = ("")

memory = ("")

if device == ("PHONE"):

 make = input ("what make of phone do you have? Iphone or Samsung or other").upper()
if make == ("IPHONE"):
    model == input("What model is your iPhone 6 or 7. If other plese spectify")

if device != ("PHONE") or ("PHONE") or (""):

  make =input("what make is your " + str(device)).upper()
  model = input("whats model is your " + str(device)).upper()
  verison = input("what verison is your " + str(device)).upper()
  memory = int(input("How much memory is in your " + str(device)))
  print(make, model, verison, memory,"GB")
  print(casenumber)
  f = open('technician.txt','a')
  f.write("**CASE NUMBER:{}** ** DEVICE: {}** **MAKE OF DEVICE: {}** **MODEL    OF DEVICE: {} **".format(casenumber,device,make,model,verison,memory))
f.write("/n")
f.close()
```

What I want for this to do is to write a on a separate line each time the program is finished. But /n does not work. I ran the program twice and all it does is write on the same line in the text file:

**CASE NUMBER:574927542749031461928599801595193290973875978** ** DEVICE: TABEL** **MAKE OF DEVICE: APPLE** **MODEL OF DEVICE: IPAD **/n**CASE NUMBER:207884437699822095837989343019189844675528960** ** DEVICE: TABLET** **MAKE OF DEVICE: APPLE** **MODEL OF DEVICE: 2 **/n

All this is on the same line. Please help

Many Thanks,

Rory Eastham

Comment: newline is "\n" and not "/n". Note the backslash.

Comment: thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline character is `\n`, as opposed to the `/n` used in your program. Updating your code with this should fix the issue you're describing.